# Wildfly: Encrypt password for EJB remote java

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, wildfly

I am trying to ecnrypt my password for EJB remote client. I tried encode64 or added it to config but nothing worked. I am not sure if it is possible. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
Context context;
final clientProperties = new Properties();
clientProperties.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");
clientProperties.put(remote.connections", default);
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.host", "server_host");
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.port", "8080");
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.username", "ejb");
clientProperties.put("remote.connection.default.password", "password");
clientProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, org.wildfly.naming.client.WildflyInitialContextFactory");
context = new InitialContext(clientProperties);
```

Comment: The client expects to be passed the password in plain text in the properties

Comment: @WillT you mean what? I tried to do it with ejb-jboss.properties but it didnt work. This is the only way for me how it works. But I do not want my password to be public or right in the code.

Comment: Might it be better to get your app to login as a real use or the application then if you don't want your client app to have it's own "system" credentials? The default security setup of the server using property files for the users is very much an example rather than necessarily what you use in a real application